# how to show title of TabBar while selecting?

Tags: swift, uitabbar, tabbar

## My TabBar has 5 Tab and I make it programmatically I have the title but I want when I run the App, title  hide and when I click on each tab that tab appear the title

import UIKit

class MainVC: UITabBarController,UITabBarControllerDelegate {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.delegate = self
    self.view.backgroundColor = .yellow
    tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.init(displayP3Red: 0, green: 0, blue: 220, alpha: 1)
    
     setuptabbar()
}
func setuptabbar() {
    
    let hometab = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeVC())
    hometab.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "home-off")
    hometab.tabBarItem.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "home-on")
    hometab.tabBarItem.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: 0);
    hometab.title = "save"
    
    let RightTab = UINavigationController(rootViewController: page1())
    RightTab.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "his-off1")
    RightTab.tabBarItem.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "his-on1")
    RightTab.tabBarItem.titlePositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: 0);
    
    RightTab.title =  "home"
    
    let LeftTab = UINavigationController(rootViewController: page2())
    LeftTab.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "support")
    LeftTab.tabBarItem.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "addmember")
    LeftTab.title = "search"

    
    let RightTab2 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: page4())
    RightTab2.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "share")
    RightTab2.tabBarItem.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "support")
    RightTab2.title = "profile"

    
    let LeftTab2 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: page5())
    LeftTab2.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "title_icon")
    LeftTab2.tabBarItem.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "addmember")
    viewControllers = [RightTab  , LeftTab, hometab , RightTab2 , LeftTab2 ]
    guard let items = tabBar.items else {return}
    for item in items{
        item.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom:0, right: 0)
        
  
    }
    
    
    
}
```

}

Comment: Can you put your code as text?

Comment: @vvv its the code

Answer (score 0):

- set default screen title unhide and other all baritem's title hide  (using viewdidload)
- on click of tabbar button unhide the title of that item and hide all
  other titles

if you don't want to hide titles then you can also do it by set same colour.

this are some code which will used

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"my title";
```

sets navigation bar title.

```
self.tabBarItem.title = @"my title";
```

sets tab bar title.

```
self.title = @"my title";
```

sets both of these.
I hope it will work for you ...:)